# Is it required to use the HDMI output when using a capture card?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, video-capture

I currently own a Nintendo Switch, and I want to capture gameplay to my desktop so that I can either stream to a service such as Twitch, or simply just use a Zoom meeting with my friends/family and share my desktop with the group.

Right now, my desktop setup has an AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series graphics card, which has 2 HDMI outputs because I have a dual screen monitor setup. When I was looking at capture cards, I came across of a mix of internal vs external, but all of them seem to have both an input and an output.

For example, I was looking at an Elgato HD60 Pro:
[image: Capture Card]

As you can see, it has both an input and an output, but my desktop is nowhere near a television set, and additionally I don't want to lose my dual screen monitor usage. Will this capture card interfere in any way with my current graphics card? Is it possible to just use the input and have the gameplay show up on my desktop in a window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The capture card will not interfere with your current display.  The audio/video you want to capture is fed into the input of the capture card.  That is the minimum requirement for it to operate.  Typically, you can see the capture using software, which comes with the capture card.

The output allows the audio/video being fed into to the computer to be output to another external display.  This simply allows you to monitor the feed for errors like the display being off, or the audio is missing, without the use of your computer's monitor.

This is how every capture card I have ever seen works.  That doesnt mean this is *always* the case.  You should refer to the capture card's documentation to be certain.  Documentation is commonly found on the manufacturer's website.